# Valgrind shows question marks

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks, valgrind

I have compiled a program using Code::Blocks. I have turned on "produce debugging symbols" under the "Debug" target, and also turned off "strip all symbols..." But when I run the program with Valgrind I get question marks in the output:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes --log-file=valgrind_output.txt
~/bin/myprg

==3766== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3766== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3766== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3766== Command: /home/xxxxxx/bin/myprg
==3766== Parent PID: 3209
==3766== 
==3766== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0xffefff978 --> 0xffed13da0
==3766==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=3062744 or greater
==3766== Invalid write of size 4
==3766==    at 0x40892B: ??? (in /home/xxxxxx/bin/myprg)
==3766==    by 0x40275C: ??? (in /home/xxxxxx/bin/myprg)
==3766==    by 0x56FB82F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
==3766==  Address 0xffed13ddc is on thread 1's stack
==3766== 
==3766== Invalid write of size 4
==3766==    at 0x408931: ??? (in /home/xxxxxx/bin/myprg)
==3766==    by 0x40275C: ??? (in /home/xxxxxx/bin/myprg)
==3766==    by 0x56FB82F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
==3766==  Address 0xffed13dd4 is on thread 1's stack
==3766== 
...
```

What is the meaning of this output, and how do I find the piece of code that is causing this error?

**Update: Solution**

The problem was with Code::Blocks. It is necessary to correctly configure the project build options for the whole project and not just the "Debug" target. So all flags except "-std=c++11" were removed from the "whole project" options, so nothing was overriding the "Debug" options. Also the linker ".o" files need to be deleted when the options are changed, to force Code::Blocks to rebuild the executable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange valgrind output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296169/strange-valgrind-output)

Comment: You should probably state the layout of your source code, and how you compiled your program. Stating how you started Valgrind would be helpful, too. Compile with `-g3` or `-g2` to ensure symbols are present. Compile with `-O1` or `-O0` to ensure accurate symbols. Also see [Preparing your Program](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.prepare) in the Valgrind Quick Start Guide.

Comment: I added the Valgrind command. I'm not sure what you mean by the layout of the source code. Code::Blocks only has "-g" no "-g2" or "-g3". Also I couldn't find "-O0".

Comment: Even after specifying -g for whole project in my code facing same issue it was not able to identify C++ symbol

Answer (score 5):

I recently had this problem and was able to resolve it by using the "--keep-debuginfo=yes" option, as suggested by the FAQ on [this page](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.unhelpful).

Comment: At last a working solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The code needs to be compiled and linked with debug info (`-g` command line option) and `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` for valgrind to show correct stack traces.

See [The stack traces given by Memcheck (or another tool) aren't helpful. How can I improve them?](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.unhelpful) for more details.

Comment: I didn't need "-fno-omit-frame-pointer", at least not so far.

Comment: I've never found the `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` to be necessary, but I'm not sure that the compiler was otherwise doing `-fomit-frame-pointer` so it may not be a useful data point.  Using **`-g`** is the key point, though — in compiling individual object files and in the link phase too.

Comment: @tyebillion I find that I often need this flag when debugging or benchmarking optimized builds with `valgrind` and `perf`. It depends on what method the tool uses to walk the stack frames. Intel VTune, for example, does not need it. In builds with no `-O` flag `fno-omit-frame-pointer` is unnecessary.

Comment: 0

I am posting this to help someone struggling with those ?? (question marks) in their valgrind output - make sure you try different versions of valgrind. I used a newer version of valgrind and all those ?? disappeared.

Comment: To complement @Mohit's comment, I had this issue with Valgrind 3.11 and upgrading it to 3.18.1 did solve the issue.